# cannot await object in the async call

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method called `DoSomething()` that returns an `object` and is time-consuming. So I would like to use *async/await* to let it run in the background while my GUI is showing a "*waiting for response...*" message.

In my calling method:

```
Task taskDoSomething = new Task(DoSomethingAsync);
taskDoSomething.Start();
taskDoSomething.Wait();
// continue the program
```

My `DoSomethingAsync` method:

```
private async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
    Object result = await DoSomething();
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> Cannot await [ObjectType]

And `[ObjectType]` is a type of object I have created myself. I just used object above not to confuse the reader.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and set me free of the scattered processing of `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how `async` and `await` works. If `DoSomething()` is a long-running method which *isn't* designed for asynchrony, you probably just want to do it in a different thread, e.g. by starting a separate task:

```
Task<object> task = Task.Run<object>(DoSomething);
```

Note that means `DoSomething` won't be able to interact with the UI, as it'll be on a different thread.

You can then `await` that task, if you want to - but only from an async method. It's hard to give more concrete advice without knowing more context.

From your comments, you might have something like:

```
private async void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<object> task = Task.Run<object>(DoSomething);
    object result = await task;
    status.Text = "I've done something";
    // Use the result?
}
```

Comment: What I want is something that works quite like `BackgroundWorker`. When the user presses the button, a `waiting for response` logo should be displayed until `DoSomethin()` finishes its job and then a status message like `Job is Done!`

Comment: @JonSkeet Aren't you blocking by calling `task.Result`?

Comment: @I3arnon: Uh, yes - that was meant to be `await task`. Not sure what happened there... fixed though.

Comment: @JonSkeet what if `DoSomething` has an argument? I am using your solution but I get the `The best overloaded method match for ... has some invalid arguments` error.

Comment: @Pedram: Then you'd use `Task.Run(() => DoSomething(argument))`. If your *example* had used an argument, so would my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

If `DoSomething` is synchronous (which it appears to be) and you want to offload it to a different thread to keep the UI responsive you should use `Task.Run`:

```
async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}
```

You should also never use `async void` unless in an event handler.
There's no reason to create a task directly. Either make `DoSomethingAsync` return a `Task` or remove that method completely and use `Task.Run` directly.

---

If however `DoSomething` is inherently asynchronous you should implement it using `async-await` and have it implicitly return a task.

Comment: I learned `async void` from http://www.dotnetperls.com/async. It works when I change your `async Task` to `async void` but now all the statements that I want to use after `Task taskDoSomething = new Task(DoSomethingAsync);` are run in parallel. I would like to know when `DoSomething()` finishes its job so I decide what to do to the user.

Comment: @Pedram That's a bad reference. You should take a look at Stephen Cleary's introduction: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html